# How do I save a Firebase storage image URL inside Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am creating an Instagram style application using Firebase.

The user would be uploading an image to Firebase storage and that works. Now I would like to relate that image to other information like a caption. What is the proper way to store the image URL in an object which has things such as caption? At the moment I store the image URL like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx-xxx.appspot.com/o/xxx.jpeg?alt=media&token=xxx` inside an imageUrl property inside an object.

I would like to know if that is how it should be done and also what are the Firebase storage rules that need to be applied to only access the images if the user is logged in?

Comment: Is that not working? Are you running into specific coding difficulties? If yes, then post your code and we will try to help. If not, probably an opinion based question/answer.

Comment: It's working but I would like to know if that is the correct way and, if yes, set the rules so that logged in users are able to view the images

Answer (score 0):

> What are the Firebase storage rules that need to be applied to only
>   access the images if the user is logged in?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules only authenticated users can access the images. This example is shown on [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules). And it's actually Firebase Storage's default rules.